# Necessary and Sufficient conditions for Product of Limit Point Compact spaces to be Limit Point Compact?

Tags: general-topology, compactness, separation-axioms, product-space

Do there exist necessary and sufficient conditions for the product of Limit Point Compact spaces to be Limit Point Compact?

I've been able to find some conditions for this to hold for Countably Compact spaces, so if the space is $T_1$, I know the conditions. But, I'm unaware of any general conditions for Limit Point Compactness.

Comment: I'd start looking in the Handbook of Set Theoretic topology, there is a chapter on countable compactness and products.

Comment: I've found conditions for Countable Compactness; I'm looking for conditions on Limit Point Compactness.

Comment: limit point compactness without $T_1$ is not very interesting IMO.